# JPA: detached entity passed to persist: nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, many-to-many

### **JPA: many-to-many connection.**

## Scenerio:

Multiple product can be saved under multiple categories. Like: **Mango can be used as Fruit category and Desert Category.**

> Product == [COMMODITY]
>
> Category == [GENRE]

## Exception:

```
detached entity passed to persist: sari.core.domain.account.Genre; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist:
```

### Commodity.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "COMMODITY")
public class Commodity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    .........
    .........
    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = {
                    CascadeType.MERGE,
                    CascadeType.PERSIST
                })
    @JoinTable(name = "commodity_genre", joinColumns = {
            @JoinColumn(name = "commodity_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                    @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<Genre> genres;
```

### Genre.java:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GENRE")
public class Genre implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 7643588406864492883L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    .........
    .........

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE }, mappedBy = "genres")
    @JsonBackReference
    private List<Commodity> commodities;
```

## My Action Plan:

1. Check if you are trying to persist an entity which has the same id
   as another entity, and which is already present in the
   PersistenceContext in your application.
2. Do not set an ID before you save or persist it. Hibernate will look
   at the Entity you’ve passed and it assumes that because it has its
   Primary Key populated that it is already in the database. Various
   blog and person, has given solution using removing setId()

But No luck. Getting stuck for hours. Any kind of help is highly appreciated.

**Resource Link:**

[Hibernate / JPA – Detached entity passed to persist exception](https://javabeat.net/hibernate-detached-entity/)

## For more, you can check full Exception Log:

```
01-04-2018 00:55:39 [g.a.c.CommodityController:55] addCommodity : addCommodity() method started!!
01-04-2018 00:55:39 [g.a.c.CommodityController:56] addCommodity : Full Model: Commodity [id=null, commodityName=Pant, price=345.0, unit=3, genres=null]
01-04-2018 00:55:39 [g.a.c.CommodityController:57] addCommodity : Genre Name is: Cloth
01-04-2018 00:55:39 [g.a.c.CommodityController:58] addCommodity : commodityName is: Pant
01-04-2018 00:55:39 [g.a.d.i.CommodityDaoImpl:124] saveCommodities : saveCommodites called
01-04-2018 00:55:39 [g.a.d.i.CommodityDaoImpl:113] checkGenreExistsInDB : checkGenreExistsInDB started
Hibernate: select genre0_.id as id1_9_, genre0_.genre_name as genre_na2_9_ from genre genre0_ where genre0_.genre_name=?
01-04-2018 00:55:39 [g.a.d.i.CommodityDaoImpl:118] checkGenreExistsInDB : checkGenreExistsInDB ended
01-04-2018 00:55:39 [g.a.d.i.CommodityDaoImpl:133] saveCommodities : genre not Exists
01-04-2018 00:55:39 [g.a.d.i.CommodityDaoImpl:135] saveCommodities : genre save in DB started
Hibernate: insert into genre (genre_name) values (?)
Hibernate: insert into commodity (commodity_name, price, unit) values (?, ?, ?)
01-04-2018 00:55:39 [g.a.d.i.CommodityDaoImpl:137] saveCommodities : genre save in DB ended
01-04-2018 00:55:39 [g.a.d.i.CommodityDaoImpl:140] saveCommodities : Size of genreList: 1
Hibernate: insert into commodity (commodity_name, price, unit) values (?, ?, ?)
01-04-2018 00:55:39 [g.c.u.GlobalExceptionHandler:58] runtimeExceptionHandle : org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: detached entity passed to persist: sari.core.domain.account.Genre; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: sari.core.domain.account.Genre
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:299)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:244)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.translateExceptionIfPossible(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:488)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.translateExceptionIfPossible(ChainedPersistenceExceptionTranslator.java:59)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.DataAccessUtils.translateIfNecessary(DataAccessUtils.java:213)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:147)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:133)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.invoke(SurroundingTransactionDetectorMethodInterceptor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:213)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy160.save(Unknown Source)
        at sari.account.dao.impl.CommodityDaoImpl.saveCommodities(CommodityDaoImpl.java:142)
        at sari.account.services.CommodityService.saveCommodities(CommodityService.java:31)
        at sari.account.controllers.CommodityController.addCommodity(CommodityController.java:59)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)
        at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:133)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:116)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:827)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:738)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:85)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:648)
        at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:230)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at sari.core.util.CorsConfiguration.doFilterInternal(CorsConfiguration.java:29)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:208)
        at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HttpPutFormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpPutFormContentFilter.java:105)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:81)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:197)
        at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:107)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:192)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:165)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:198)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:474)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:349)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:783)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:798)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1434)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: sari.core.domain.account.Genre
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:124)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:765)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:758)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener$1.cascade(JpaPersistEventListener.java:80)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeToOne(Cascade.java:398)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:323)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollectionElements(Cascade.java:431)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeCollection(Cascade.java:363)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeAssociation(Cascade.java:326)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascadeProperty(Cascade.java:162)
        at org.hibernate.engine.internal.Cascade.cascade(Cascade.java:111)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.cascadeAfterSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:456)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSaveOrReplicate(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:278)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.performSave(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:178)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractSaveEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(AbstractSaveEventListener.java:109)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.event.internal.core.JpaPersistEventListener.saveWithGeneratedId(JpaPersistEventListener.java:67)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.entityIsTransient(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:189)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultPersistEventListener.onPersist(DefaultPersistEventListener.java:58)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:775)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:748)
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:753)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.spi.AbstractEntityManagerImpl.persist(AbstractEntityManagerImpl.java:1146)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:298)
        at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy156.persist(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.save(SimpleJpaRepository.java:508)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:504)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:489)
        at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:461)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:61)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:99)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:282)
        at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:136)
        ... 76 more

01-04-2018 00:55:39 [g.c.u.GlobalExceptionHandler:77] <init> : Status: 200
01-04-2018 00:55:39 [g.c.u.GlobalExceptionHandler:78] <init> : Message : detached entity passed to persist: sari.core.domain.account.Genre; nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: sari.core.domain.account.Genre
01-04-2018 00:55:39 [g.c.u.GlobalExceptionHandler:79] <init> : Trace: Resource Not Available
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

At last, I got my solution for Many-to-Many connection in JPA.

### Root Cause Analysis:

In a JPA many-to-many relationship, if cascade type has been set at `CascadeType.PERSIST` (or `CascadeType.ALL`, which includes CascadeType.PERSIST), then while saving the parent and updating it with references of the child, it will try to save the child again.

**Following Issues can appear:**

Child is already in persistence store `(A detached instance has been passed)` -in this case it will throw an exception `“org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist”`

### Solution:

**Use this:**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.MERGE,
                CascadeType.REFRESH
            })
@JoinTable(name = "commodity_genre", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "commodity_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Genre> genres;
```

**Instead of:**

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = {
                CascadeType.MERGE,
                CascadeType.PERSIST
            })
@JoinTable(name = "commodity_genre", joinColumns = {
        @JoinColumn(name = "commodity_id", referencedColumnName = "id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "genre_id", referencedColumnName = "id") })
@JsonManagedReference
private List<Genre> genres;
```

For JPA, the best option would be to query for entity on the server side before trying to save it.

- If its sure that only new child will be added, and not a detached
  instance from DB, `CascadeType.PERSIST` will take care of it.
- On the other hand, if the requirement is never to add a new child if it's
  not already in DB then `CascadeType.PERSIST` should be removed and
  `cascade={CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH}` should be used

### Resource Link:

[Persisting a detached entity in JPA](https://chandanpandey.com/2012/12/22/persisting-a-detached-entity-in-jpa/)

Comment: hi @SkyWalker. Link is broken.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was using `Cascade.ALL` instead of `Cascade.MERGE`.