# How to update list of child entities when i have ManyToMany relationship (spring-boot/spring-data-jpa)?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have Product and Category entities. There is ManyToMany relationship between them and Product is relationship owner, so when I call action to create/save Product(with category1 and category2 for example) two queries are called:

1. insert into Products...
2. insert into ProductCategory...

And that is expected behavior.

But, when I add/remove come categories and try to call update(fetch product from db, set new values, and call save again) then these two queries are called:

1. update Products...
2. update Categories...

MY GOAL is to update just "products" table, and update JOIN TABLE("ProductCategory").

Here are related domain classes:

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "products")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class Product extends BaseEntityAudit {

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@Column(name = "description")
private String description;

@NotEmpty
@Column(name = "code")
private String code;

@NotNull
@Column(name = "price")
private Double price;

@Column(name = "published", nullable = true)
private boolean published;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "product")
private List<Order> orders;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ecommerce_id", nullable = false)
private ECommerce eCommerce;

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
        cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH })
@JoinTable(
        name = "CategoryProduct",
        joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "product_id") },
        inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "category_id") }
)
private List<Category> categories;
}

@Entity
@Data
@Table(name = "categories")
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
public class Category extends BaseEntityAudit {

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "ecommerce_id", nullable = false)
private ECommerce eCommerce;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "categories",
            cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH } )

private List<Product> products;
}
```

And this is service method which handles update request:

```
@Override
public ProductResponse update(CreateUpdateProductRequest request,
                        String productId) throws ProductNotFoundException {
    Product product = productRepository.getOne(Long.valueOf(productId));

    productTransformer.productRequestToProduct(request, product);
    return productTransformer.productToProductResponse(
        productRepository.save(product));
}
```

And CreateUpdateProductRequest to Product transformer:

```
public void productRequestToProduct(CreateUpdateProductRequest request, 
Product product) {
    ECommerce eCommerce = new ECommerce();
    eCommerce.setId(Long.valueOf(request.getECommerceId()));
    product.setName(request.getName());
    product.setDescription(request.getDescription());
    product.setCode(request.getCode());
    product.setPrice(request.getPrice());

    product.setCategories(
        categoriesRequestToDomain(request.getCategoryIds()
    ));
    product.setECommerce(eCommerce);
}
```

What should I do to keep records in JOIN TABLE(ProductCategory) up to date using just power of spring-data-jpa?

Comment: "What should I do to keep records in JOIN TABLE(ProductCategory)?" - Why would you want to keep an association if it is no more valid?

Comment: @LppEdd I just edited post, read that part again. I want to delete invalid ones, and add new ones. Thank You.

Comment: Change CascadeType.REFRESH to CascadeType.PERSIST on both sides

Comment: @LppEdd It does not work for my case. I first used PERSIST and i was getting 
PersistentObjectException: detached entity passed to persist: com.designdropshipping.app.data.domain.Category".. Then I found a solution here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592081/jpa-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-nested-exception-is-org-hibernate-persis

Comment: @LppEdd Added it on both sides, still same issue.