# org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

This is my orderservice implementation for creating and saving orders here with the customerid I'm getting customer and customer has a cart and in the cart product list is there and for that product list, I should create an order.

```
public Order save(int custid) {
        Optional<Customer> cust = customerRepo.findById(custid);//here customer is there and inside customer cart is there inside cart medicine list is there.
        Cart ct= cust.get().getCart();//getting cart from customer
        if(ct.getMedicineList().size()!=0) {//create order only if the medicine list is not empty. there are 8 fields **orderDate,dispatchDate,status,medicineList,totalCost,customer and orderId(GeneratedValue)** I can't set the orderId cuz it is auto generated.
            LocalDate todaysDate = LocalDate.now();
            LocalDate dispatchdate = todaysDate.plusDays(3);
            List<Medicine> orderList= new ArrayList<Medicine>();
            List<Medicine> cartList= new ArrayList<Medicine>();
            cartList=ct.getMedicineList();
            orderList.addAll(cartList);
            Order ord = new Order();
            ord.setCustomer(cust.get());
            ord.setMedicineList(orderList);
            ord.setDispatchDate(dispatchdate);
            ord.setOrderDate(todaysDate);
            ord.setStatus("Placed");
            ord.setTotalCost((float)ct.getTotalAmount());
            logger.info("Add order to the database");
            return orderRepository.save(ord);
        }
        return null;
        
    }
```

this is my order controller

```
@PostMapping("/order/{custid}")
    public ResponseEntity<Order> addOrder(@Valid @PathVariable("custid") int custid) {
        logger.info("Add order in database");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(orderService.save(custid), HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

this is my medicine Entity

```
@Data
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@ToString
@Table(name = "medicine")
@Entity
public class Medicine {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "medicine_id", nullable = false)
    @NonNull
    @GeneratedValue
    private int medicineId;
    
    @NonNull
    @Size(min = 3, message = "Minimum charecters in medicine name should be 3.")
    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique = true, name = "medicine_name", nullable = false)
    
    private String medicineName;
    
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "medicine_cost", nullable = false)
    private float medicineCost;
    
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "mfd", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate mfd;
    
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "expiry_date", nullable = false)
    private LocalDate expiryDate;
    
    @NonNull
    @Column(name = "medicine_quantity", nullable = false)
    private int medicineQuantity = 1;
    @NonNull
    private String medicineCategory;
    @NonNull
    private String medicineDescription;



    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "medicineList",fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Order> orderList;
}
```

this is my order Entity

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString

    public class Order {
        @Id
        @Column(name = "orderId")
        @GeneratedValue
        private int orderId;
        @NonNull
        private LocalDate orderDate;
        @ManyToMany(targetEntity = Medicine.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
        @JoinTable(name = "ord_med", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "ord_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = {
                @JoinColumn(name = "med_id") })
        private List<Medicine> medicineList = new ArrayList<>();
        @NonNull
        private LocalDate dispatchDate;
        @NotEmpty
        private float totalCost;
        @NonNull
        private String status;
        
        @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
        @JoinColumn(name="c_ord_fk",referencedColumnName = "customerId")
        @NonNull
        private Customer customer;
        
    }
```

here when i try to create order for the list inside cart it gives me *[36m.m.m.a.ExceptionHandlerExceptionResolver[0;39m [2m:[0;39m Resolved [org.springframework.transaction.TransactionSystemException: Could not commit JPA transaction; nested exception is javax.persistence.RollbackException: Error while committing the transaction]*
i'm not sure but i think its because of the id but it is autogenerated. Idk how to create an order object for the list of products or is this the correct way to do it.

Comment: why do you have ManyToMany on medicineList?
It doesn't make sense. What you have done is each Medicine in the cart can belong to many orders, that is impossible right? Once this guy buy's something that medicine object should be assigned only to him, it cannot be part of some other cart.

Comment: You need something called Product or Medicine - can be medicine with particular name, company, cost so on.
You need ProductInstance or MedicineInstance - which will be added to cart - which will refer to Product/Medicine object - this ProductInstance can have it's own discounted price and it will be refered in Cart

Comment: please take a look now, I have added my medicine entity , one medicine can be in many orders and one order can have many medicines. please correct me if iam wrong.

Comment: See according to my thought process your model doesn't look good. let that be kept aside, it's your choice.
Coming to your problem - first check why the transaction is rolled back? Check generated SQL query what is being sent to the DB, understand what is the error

Answer (score 0):

Actually I found the answer, all I have to do is when you use **ManyToMany** mapping the cascade type must be cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE,CascadeType.REFRESH} instead of {cascade = CascadeType.ALL} and it works fine. reference [JPA: detached entity passed to persist: nested exception is org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49592081/jpa-detached-entity-passed-to-persist-nested-exception-is-org-hibernate-persis)